# Evaluating the triple integral of $ f(x,y,z) = e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}} $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

as part of a math tutorial I am supposed to evaluate the following integral:

$$ \int_{-1}^1
\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}
e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}
dz \ dy \ dx$$

Now I am pretty sure this is over the unit sphere with $$-1\leq x \leq 1,
\ \ \ -\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{1-x^2},
 \ \ \ -\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\ \ \ $$

so I tried using spherical coordinates and changing the integral to

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}
\int_{0}^{\pi}
\int_{0}^1
e^{(\rho^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\rho^2 \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d \theta$$
which simplifies to
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}
\int_{0}^{\pi}
\int_{0}^1
e^{\rho^3}\rho^2 \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d \theta$$

Already in this step, I am unsure if the new integral boundaries are correct and if the substitution is correct. I tried plugging in $\rho = 1$, but this does not yield the correct result. (WolframAlpha says the value should be ~7.19)

Comment: Given that you're integrating over $\rho$, I'm not sure how plugging in $\rho =  1$ would give you anything meaningful. Otherwise, the integral looks fine.

Comment: @eyeballfrog So then for the integration, I suppose the correct way to do it would be to substitute $ u = \rho^3$ and $du = 3\rho^2 d\rho$?

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks, how I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral looks fine. Using the $u$-substitution you suggested in the comments, you should get $4\pi(e-1)/3$, which agrees with WolframAlpha.